# Android UI automation with Python - Monkeyrunner - Null point exception

Tags: monkeyrunner

Code:

## Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

## Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

print "Hello World!"

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AndroidApps\Sample\src\com\android\diagnostics\click\click1.py", line 5, in 
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(MonkeyRunner.java:74)

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException

I am trying to automate the android application by using monkey runner i.e UI testing by using python scripts
Can any body help how to solve the Null point exception for the above code ?

Comment: It looks like this is an issue with connecting to the device. Are you connecting to a real or emulated device? Is the device on? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Does 'adb devices' show your device?

Comment: can you please tell me how to write and run the script? Which IDE do I need, I have been reading about monkey, but did not find any post that describe , how will I do this...I am asking about the every basic steps...

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the stack trace of your error, this looks like there is an issue with your jython library of monkeyrunner.

Because, there is an exception occurring from reflection package which is failing to invoke the native java call. Make sure your monkeyrunner.bat file is referencing the lib folder provided with android SDK.

Updating the android SDK also may help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.At last I found that is a hardware issue, so please ran it on emulator first or another phone.